# Access DataContext instance in code when set in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I usually instantiate my ViewModel in codebehind and set it as the DataContext for the Window or UserControl.

For this simple ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> items { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        items.Add("FirstItem");
        items.Add("SecondItem");
        items.Add("ThirdItem");
    }
}
```

i am adding my local namespace and the following syntax will set the things right:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Fine, i understand that a ViewModel object is instantiated and set as DataContext for the window, it works as expected but is there any way to access the instantiated object from code?

If i create the object in the codebehind with

```
ViewModel vm = new VewModel();
this.DataContext = vm;
```

i am able to access vm instance but with the XAML approach, how can it be reached?

I've created this small example in order to find out if there is a simple answer available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you set the `DataContext` of *any* element, then all of the children of said element will also have the same `DataContext`.

Picture the scene:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Here you have given the `Window` a `DataContext`. Now, all child elements within your window effectively have the same `DataContext`.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />
```

To get hold of the `DataContext` in code-behind, you can simply reference the `DataContext` of the element.

```
ViewModel vm = (ViewModel)this.DataContext;
```

The code above references the `DataContext` of the `Window`.

If you need to be more specific, and get the `DataContext` of a **specific** element, then you can simply reference the element by name.

```
ViewModel vm = (ViewModel)elementName.DataContext;
```

All that aside, you should *never* set the `DataContext` in code-behind. The MVVM design pattern likes to keep things separated, and if you start setting the `DataContext` of a `UserControl` for example, then things get screwed up pretty quickly.

Setting the `DataContext` in XAML is the right way to go.

Comment: +1, but setting the `DataContext` in XAML isn't always the right way. If your ViewModel is injected through your View's constructor, then setting it in code-behind is the right way to go, for instance.